# Threading in BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: multithreading, biztalk, orchestration

I want to get some records from the Database and then on the basis of the User ID and Password as credentials I need to call another web-service. 
I want to do this using threading with in Orchestration? Can I do threading with in orchestration. Means can I start some threads in Orchestration it self to make this thing work faster.

Thanks,
Dinesh Arora.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are looking for is scalability / concurrency, what I believe you need to do is:

- Use the WCF-SQL Adapter in a receive location to call / poll your Database table / PROC
- Debatch the XML result into separate messages (with or without envelope - See this [Richard Seroter post](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/debatching-inbound-messages-from-biztalk-wcf-sql-adapter/))
- Subscribe an orchestration to the debatched (single) message schema,
  which maps the data and calls the web service

You shouldn't directly be concerned with threading in BizTalk orchestrations (unless you are e.g. writing a new Adapter). e.g. BizTalk may choose to dehydrate your orchestration at a suitable point.

BizTalk will concurrently call the Web Service with as many messages as possible - this will depend on the number of messages returned from SQL, the number of host instances and send adapter threads on your BTS servers, as well as the actually throughput of the downstream web service.